# how to save angularjs data into a file to the server?

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee

i'm trying to transfer data between my front end part to my back end part by using angularjs and java EE. Currently, i have this angularjs variable :

```
$scope.result
```

i'd like to transfer this variable to my back end part. After some research, i tried to use a post method by using this :

```
$http.post('/IndexServlet', $scope.result, null).then("ok", "error");
```

And then try to see if something happens to my servlet in the doPost method.
If anyone knows how to make this work it will be great. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If anyone wants to do the same thing you need to do this in angularjs :

```
var queryParams = {params: {op: $scope.result}};/* Query Parameters*/
    $http.post("processing" /* URL */, null, queryParams)
            .success(function(serverResponse, status, headers, config) {
                alert("ok");
            }).error(function(serverResponse, status, headers, config) {
                alert("failure");
            }
        );
```

And in java EE you have to attach the URL /processing to your servlet and then implement the doPost(...) method in the servlet. To retrieve the value you transfered you need to call this method :

```
req.getParameter("op");
```